# Via Epia 800 bios update

Tags: bios, flashing

i have a via epia 800 motherboard with no floppy, neither cd rom. 
I would like to update BIOS to allow me to boot via HDD USB  ... 
I've tried to update bios using FreeDos and the via flash update bios.. but it now work..
Somebody can help me ?
Thanks

Comment: judging by darokthar's answer, it doesn't look promising. Have you tried calling them? I called VIA once about something. Report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual states what you should do. Either install DOS 6.22, or Win 98 then update the BIOS with the VIA tool. This basically s.... but this is the way VIA designed the BIOS update tool. I'm sorry for you. Maybe you have a Win98 CD or a DOS installer at hand? If you haven't maybe you could get one in a local computer store, at ebay or take a less lawful approach.

And the manual states on pages 11-12 some other possibilities why an update is not possible. I don't know if this is case for your mainboard.

There could be a jumper, which might have to be set, or an BIOS option. Maybe it is possible to use a Win 98 CD without installing Win 98 and just boot to the command line.

Comment: a link to the manual would've been good

Comment: @barlop Just go to the via homepage and look up the board. The manual is included with the bios update. http://www.via.com.tw/en/products/embedded/ProductDetail.jsp?productLine=1&id=1030&tabs=1